# List of titles to display in listveiw wedget

Tags: flutter

---

**flutter list of things**

I need to make a list of titles
And display it on a listveiw builder for flutter
How can i do that by code

Comment: The ListView.builder has many examples, as it is one of the most common widgets.  Have you gone through the codelabs, and the documentation for the widget?  Do you have a more specific answerable question?  Have you googled for "flutter listview tutorial" to see what articles and videos come up?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter's ListView.builder() method does this very easily

This is an example showing a list of Text widgets:

```
List<String> list = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder(context, index) {
    return textWidget(list[index]);
}
)


Widget textWidget(String text) {
  return Text(text);
}
```